# Using shell script to move file after failed execution of Xfoil.

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have Used [this](https://github.com/asurath/airfoil-analysis) script to get majority of my code. I am trying to edit it where the code continually runs even when getting stuck on a file. What happens with original dataanalysis.sh script is that some files takes really long time, 2-3 days, to run in xfoil or it just freezes. Thats where

```
 timeout 1s xfoil $file < xfoil.com
```

comes in. I want this stop xfoil from running and go to next file. Where I am having problems is with the if loop:

```
if [ $? = 124 ]; then
                xargs mv -t $file < /Failed/$file
                it failed
fi
```

This is supposed to move the troublesome file to Failed folder so that I can easily view and possibly fix them. I had debug set up before where it did tell me which files failed so I think the if statement does get executed but the file never moves. I have researched this and am lost at this point. Please help.

```
#!/bin/sh

bash -x ./script.sh
exec 5> debug_output.txt
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
PS4='$lineno: '

cd ./airfoils

mkdir Failed



echo "failed airfoils" > failed.dat

#Then we loop over each file in the working directory whose name ends with .dat
for file in ./*.dat
do
        #we write commands to a text file called xfoil.com, this first line overwrite the file and the subsequent lines append to it
        echo "pane" > xfoil.com
        echo "oper" >> xfoil.com
        echo "visc 6.5e5" >> xfoil.com
        echo "pacc" >> xfoil.com
        #this is the only real dynamic line which we need
        echo $file'.analysis' >> xfoil.com
        echo "" >> xfoil.com
        echo "aseq 0 14 1.0" >> xfoil.com
        echo "pacc" >> xfoil.com
        echo "" >> xfoil.com
        echo "quit" >> xfoil.com

        set -x

        #we then run xfoil with its STDIN hooked up to the text file where we just wrote the commands to
        echo $file
        timeout 1s xfoil $file < xfoil.com

        if [ $? = 124 ]; then
                xargs mv -t $file < /Failed/$file
                it failed
        fi

        #finally we delete the dat file as we have created the polar

        set +x

        rm $file
done
```

This is the entire script

I ran it as

```
bash data.sh
```

---

Comment: The syntax for moving a file to a target dir is either `mv file dir/` or `mv -t dir/ file` - I don't get how you came up with `xargs mv -t $file < /Failed/$file`. Also the exit status test should probably use `-eq` not `=` i.e. `[ $? -eq 124 ]` (`=` is for string comparisons)

Comment: @steeldriver I have tried that, I came up with it [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115734/move-file-by-list-in-file). I have tried same advise before also. After I have found this latest solution I came here. I tried many terms for this and came empty. ---

the statement now:---

if [ $? -eq 124 ]; then---
                mv file Failed/---
                it failed---
        fi---

Comment: `it failed` isn't a valid command - did you perhaps mean to write `echo "it failed"`? Also the directory `Failed` must exist for this to work

Comment: The Directory does exist and have removed "it failed" line. It still doesnt move the file